# What is considered to be the last event described chronologically in major Hindu texts?

Tags: time

In Hindu mythology, which is rich in stories and events spanning across different texts and time periods, what is considered to be the last event that happened chronologically in the timeline of events described in the major texts? For example, if we were discussing Christianity, **Jesus’ resurrection from the cross** is the last event described in the Bible.

Comment: Lord Kalki's arrival. Yet to come.

Comment: By Christian precept of creation, events occur infinitely linear.. , since a certain starting point, ensuing a definite first / last event.Whereas in Hinduism , one has to accommodate the doctrine of Kalpa bhedha, upon an anecdote of Purana, owing to cyclically sustaining creation(as that of seasons).as one can't say , this is the first/last season.So chronology is relevant only within a range or a context

Comment: @Athrey - cyclic does not mean non-linear. time is always linear. cyclic just refers to repeating, like seasons are cyclic. doesn't mean the past happened after the future. what happened in the past is the past. it might happen again, but that's a 2-time occurence. if it happens yet again that's a 3rd occurrence. this happens infinitely repeatingly on a linear scale.

Comment: @mar , If it is said that , time is always linear , then there should be a point in time that indicates an absolute beginning , (Christian notion) a sufficient reference, to enumerate an absolute chronology of   events.I hope by  the word linear , you meant  continuity of time .(yet it is subjective and temporal , thus requires a context or a demarcation).Puranas may have anectodes (of future as well) that  span across kalpas. How come, this question can be answered as , this is the absolute last event described in Puranas, parallel to Christian texts.So a context in addition is required,

Comment: as part of question.(Anyway this is my understanding)
Esoteric view point of Kala Chakra , is also detailed in texts like yoga vasishta , which may be beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: "then there should be a point in time that indicates an absolute beginning" - not if time is infinite.
kala chakra is eka dik. it is just depicted as chakra because of several repeating events. but each of those events happened "again". It's not a depiction of the past. If I brush my teeth yesterday, today and tomorrow, that's 3 separate but same events. not 1 single event. that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Teeth brushing tomorrow is  a future event , wrt , to teeth brushing yesterday , So here,  the distinction(as you said) is felt  by a Kalapramana. So, IMO, the last event to be cited from scriptures requires , atleast a basis of a Kala pramana.(else, What could be the last event in a  Kala which  is anadhi and anantha ) yet nothing occurs arbitrary /random...Whereas by Christian doctrine, events are arbitrary(since the ex nihilo creation that began at a point ) , so Kala pramana may not be necessary there.